Prove $ f_n \to 0 $ almost everywhere for a sequence of measurable functions with given measure condition
Let $ \{f_n\} $ be a sequence of Lebesgue measurable functions on $ \mathbb{R} $ such that:
$$
m\left(\{x \in \mathbb{R} : |f_n(x)| > \frac{1}{n}\}\right) < \frac{1}{n^2},
$$
where m denotes the Lebesgue measure.
Problem Statement:
Prove that $ f_n(x) \to 0$  almost everywhere using the definition of convergence almost everywhere.
My Attempt:
I considered the set:
$$
A = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : f_n(x) \text{ does not converge to } 0\}.
$$
For each ( n ), define:
$$
A_n = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : |f_n(x)| > \frac{1}{n}\}.
$$
Since $ f_n(x) $ does not converge to 0, we have:
$$
\limsup_{n \to \infty} |f_n(x)| > 0.
$$
This implies that:
$$
A = \bigcap_{N=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{n=N}^{\infty} A_n.
$$
Is this representation correct? Does it properly capture the set of points where $ f_n(x) $ does not converge to 0? Any insights or confirmations would be appreciated.

Correct, that is a canonical proof. In general, it is Borel-Cantelli lemma.

When you say “Since $f_n(x)$ does not converge…”, do you mean to say “for $x \in A$“?.
Also when you say “this implies that:” I might have been tempted to leave it as a claim that A is included in the right hand side (which is all you need).

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-verification: For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.

Thank you for your feedback. Yes, when I say “Since $ f_n(x) $ does not converge…”, I mean “for $ x \in A $”. I am proving that $ f_n(x) \to 0 $ a.e., assuming $A$ is the set where $ f_n(x) $ does not converge to 0.
Regarding $ A \subseteq \bigcap_{N=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{n=N}^{\infty} A_n $, I see your point. Showing the inclusion may suffice to prove $ A $ has measure zero, implying convergence a.e.
Is my approach incorrect? Should I state only $ A \subseteq \bigcap_{N=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{n=N}^{\infty} A_n $ instead of equality?

Yes, it's correct, though awkwardly written and also incomplete. As mentioned previously, it is an immediate consequence of the Borel-Cantelli lemma.

yes, but I was asked to prove it without using Borel-Cantelli lemma
